# TYPO3 7.6.x Creating a MD5 encrypted Passwordfield in the TCA

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-tca

I tried creating a password field using Typo3's 'eval' functions.

TYPO3 Version 7.6.9

Here is my config:

```
'password' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_pin.password',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 50,
                'eval' => 'nospace,required,md5,unique,password'
            )
        ),
```

if i leave out the 'password' at the end the field gets saved normaly but as soon as i add it, the password field no longer updates/saves.

Comment: You ***SHOULD NOT*** use md5 for password hashing, it's easy to break. Use BCRYPT or something. If using PHP, then use the functions `password_hash` and `password_verify`. They automatically salt the password, and when additionally using `password_needs_rehash`, can be set used to automatically update to a newer/stronger hashing algorithm when the currently used one becomes to weak.

Comment: Also note that MD5 is *not* encryption, so your question title is incorrect. MD5 is a hashing algorithm, as are BCRYPT and all other similar methods for securing a password. Hashing is not the same as encryption.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to add the md5 and unique as eval parameters. In 7.x passwords are automatically encrypted with the saltedpasswords system extension and it is safer than md5. Passwords normally are not unique, so i guess it is there by mistake, but it should actually also work with unique.

```
        'password' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_pin.password',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 50,
                'eval' => 'nospace,required,password'
            )
        ),
```

later you can check the password this way:
`$hash` is the password hash from your db and `$password` is the playin password you are checking

```
        if (\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::isLoaded('saltedpasswords') && \TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Utility\SaltedPasswordsUtility::isUsageEnabled('FE')) {
            $saltObject = \TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Salt\SaltFactory::getSaltingInstance(NULL);
            return $saltObject->checkPassword($password, $hash);
        } elseif ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['loginSecurityLevel'] == 'md5') {
            return $password == md5($password);
        } elseif ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['loginSecurityLevel'] === 'sha1') {
            return $password == sha1($password);
        }
```